# JS - Копирование в буфер обмена

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как скопировать данные из атрибута `data-s=""` в буфер обмена?

Comment: Никак? Если бы любая веб-страничка имела доступ к вашему буферу обмена, вам бы это вряд ли понравилось.

Comment: Достать данные из аттрибута и получить их в js - легко. Поместить в буфер обмена - никак. Без флеш, по крайней мере.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын, Не совсем никак, но не везде поддерживается

Comment: @Grundy про копирование **выделенного текста** слышал (https://habrahabr.ru/post/256027/). А что, можно и произвольные данные в буфер отправить? Этого не знал...

Answer (score 11):

Доступ к `data-*` получить легко: У элементов есть свойство `dataset`, у которого ключами установлены существующие у элемента атрибуты `data-*`.

```
document.querySelector('#myElement').dataset.s;
```

---

С копированием сложно, но возможно.
Вот функция, которая уже довольно давно исправно работает (используем с осторожностью, поддержка может хромать, хотя основные браузеры последних версий вроде работают):

```js
function copy(str){
  let tmp   = document.createElement('INPUT'), // Создаём новый текстовой input
      focus = document.activeElement; // Получаем ссылку на элемент в фокусе (чтобы не терять фокус)

  tmp.value = str; // Временному input вставляем текст для копирования

  document.body.appendChild(tmp); // Вставляем input в DOM
  tmp.select(); // Выделяем весь текст в input
  document.execCommand('copy'); // Магия! Копирует в буфер выделенный текст (см. команду выше)
  document.body.removeChild(tmp); // Удаляем временный input
  focus.focus(); // Возвращаем фокус туда, где был
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  let input = document.querySelector('#input'),
      bCopy = document.querySelector('#bCopy'),
      log   = document.querySelector('#log');
  
  bCopy.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if(input.value){
      try{
        copy(input.value);
        log.style.color = 'green';
        log.innerHTML = 'Скопировано!';
      }catch(e){
        log.style.color = 'red';
        log.innerHTML = 'Ошибка!';
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
Введите текст: <input type='text' id='input' /> <input type='button' id='bCopy' value='Copy!' /><br />
<span id='log'></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Достать данные из аттрибута и получить их в JS - легко. Выбирайте из вариантов:

```
$('selector').attr('data-s');

$('selector').data('s');

$('selector').data().s;
```

В вот поместить эти данные в буфер обмена - на JS без дополнительных средств типа flash - никак. JS не имеет доступа к буферу обмена (и слава богу!)